# How to change default App Icon and Splash Screen in Ionic 4 application?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, ionic4

I'm developing Ionic 4 app with angular. But, I have stuck in how to change the default App Icon and Splash Screen. I've already go through the Ionic 4 documentation (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/splash-screen#usage) but din't find any suitable solution yet. In StakOverflow I've found **Lottie Splash Screen** which is one kind of solution but not similar how Ionic default Splash screen works. So, do you have any suggestion how to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I use ionic 3 and I think ionic 4 its the same ,  in your project folder ,  you have a resources directory, go in.
To change the default icon , just  change the `icon.png` by your image,  if I remember you need to resize your image (1024*1024).
To change the default splashscreen, its the same (2732*2732).
Don't forget to rename your image (icon.png and splash.png)

And after change, just update your project :

`ionic cordova resources`

Comment: When I changed icon.png and splash.png and ran the command I got this error:

`[cordova-res] 2019-11-29T09:39:53.159Z cordova-res:image Source file missing: resources/android/icon-foreground.png
[cordova-res] 2019-11-29T09:39:53.159Z cordova-res:image Source file missing: resources/android/icon-foreground.jpg
[cordova-res] 2019-11-29T09:39:53.159Z cordova-res:image Source file missing: resources/android/icon-foreground.jpeg`

Comment: what version u use ? try to delete the folder android from cordova and reload

Comment: `[cordova-res] ERROR: Missing source for "adaptive-icon" (sources: resources/android/icon-background.png, resources/android/icon-background.jpg, resources/android/icon-background.jpeg)` I get an error after changing the icon.png the same size, and re-add android platform  and it doesn't work properly

Answer (score 4):

The source image for icons should ideally be at least 1024×1024px and located at resources/icon.png. The source image for splash screens should ideally be at least 2732×2732px and located at resources/splash.png. If you used `ionic start` (run in your terminal within your app folder), there should already be default Ionic resources in the resources/ directory, which you can overwrite.
`ionic cordova resources`(run in your terminal within your app folder) will automatically update your config.xml to reflect the changes in the generated images, which Cordova then configures.

Comment: When I try to run this I get "[ERROR] Could not find cordova integration in the default project."